# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'T70001' to data type int?

Tags: sql, join, casting, type-conversion, inner-join

I am receiving the above error when using the below query

```
 SELECT  b.*,E.SSNO
  FROM [SRV-RVS].[dbo].[CARD] b
  INNER JOIN [SRV-RVS].dbo.EMP e
  on b.EMPID=E.SSNO 
  WHERE E.SSNO LIKE 't%'
```

I am trying to join both tables, here my EMPID is same as SSNO but it got a character in the begining .

Hope you got it

Regards

Comment: When you say "EMPID is same as SSNO but it got a character in the begining", do you mean EMPID _always_ starts with a letter (and only one).?After the letter it's identical to SSNO?

Comment: @HoneyBadger , yes

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert `EMPID` to a `varchar` and add a `'T'` character in the join clause.

```
SELECT  b.*,E.SNO
FROM [SRV-RVS].[dbo].[CARD] b INNER JOIN [SRV-RVS].dbo.EMP e ON ('T' + REPLACE(STR(CAST(b.EMPID as varchar(9)), 9), SPACE(1), '0')) = E.SSNO 
WHERE E.SNO LIKE 't%'
```

---

Additional notes

- I guessed on the length of the varchar but SSN is generally always 9 digits. If you are storing mask/space characters like `-` in your `SSNO` column this code will not work.
- There is code in there to left 0 pad the id for SSN numbers that start with 0 as an int to string will not automatically pad 0.
- If there data sets are large this could cause performance problems.
- Really the schema should never have converted SSN to an int (numeric) to begin with. It should have stayed as a varchar field and ideally not set as a primary key on another table either.

Again (continue from last bullet), change the schema or add a computed column. This is currently a poor design.

Comment: great.. Could you tell me how the Cast and T works here

Comment: @coffemug - You have a query that looks for SSN that starts with `T`, so if you want to join on this with a column that does not have a `T` you have to either strip it on one side or add it to the other....

Comment: @coffemug - your data types are not the same. You have to cast one side to be the same as the other, hence the `CAST` and I choose to convert to `varchar` over converting the other side to `int` which is what your query above did.

Comment: @Igor "I am also not sure if it is possible to have an SSN that starts with 0."  Mine starts with a 0 (and it's a legit number).

Answer (score 1):

Fix your table so you can do the join.  The rest of this answer assumes you are using SQL Server (based on the syntax of the code in the question).

I would encourage you to do:

```
alter table emp
    add column ssno as ( cast(stuff(empid, 1, 1, '') as int) );
```

Or to whatever type matches.  You can even build an index on this.

Then your code doesn't have to remember business rules about the relationship between `empid` and `ssno`.

Answer (score 1):

Join on table by extracting numeric values from string, so it would match on Id Column. It should return result as long u dint have any other surprises in the rowdata. This works by eliminating character in the beginning.

```
  SELECT  b.*,E.SSNO
  FROM [SRV-RVS].[dbo].[CARD] b
  INNER JOIN [SRV-RVS].dbo.EMP e
  on right(b.EMPID, len(b.EMPID) - (PatIndex('%[0-9]%', b.EMPID )-1) ) 
     =right(E.SSNO, len(E.SSNO) - (PatIndex('%[0-9]%', E.SSNO )-1) )
```